Is it possible to create an app (accessible through a link) using streamlit and a private github repository?
I read that it was possible:
https://docs.streamlit.io/deploy/streamlit-community-cloud/share-your-app
But I wasn't able to do it.
I tried using the TOKEN, but I always got Error 404.
Is there a specific way of doing it? Thanks for any information or guide.

If you read that it's possible, doesn't this already answer your question?

Show me how. I couldn't do it, that's why I am asking...

You are asking if it's possible. My answer is that if you have read that is possible, then this already answers your question.
